# problem in creating new environment using listings package

Tags: listings, environments

I want to create a new environment the make my TeX works easier:

```
\begin{latin}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
    In [1]: x = 1

    In [2]: x
    Out[2]: 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{latin}
```

I know `listings` has some problem for making new environment so it has its own `\newlstenvironment`, I tried to make new environment using  this methods which I find in `StackOverflow` and on `listings` documentation but I get same error.

method 1:

```
\newenvironment{ppp}{%
    \begin{latin} \begin{lstlisting}}{%
        \end{lstlisting} \end{latin}}
```

method 2:

```
\lstnewenvironment{ppp}
{\begin{latin}
\lstset{language=python}} { \end{latin}}
```

Is it possible to create a new environment? How can I do that?

Comment: What is the `latin` environment?

Comment: When customizing `lstlisting`, or any other package that typesets stuff verbatim such as `fancyvrb`, you should strictly adhere to the package documentation.

Comment: latin is an environment from xepersian  package that let you write English( left to right direction) in a Persian (right to left direction) Document.

Comment: The second method is the one that I wrote using package documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the “internal” form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont{Scheherazade}

\lstnewenvironment{ppp}
  {\latin\lstset{language=python}}
  {\endlatin}

\begin{document}

سلام این یک آزمون است.

\begin{ppp}
In [1]: x = 1

In [2]: x
Out[2]: 1
\end{ppp}

سلام این یک آزمون است.

\end{document}
```

[image]